# Which version of Firefox (geckodriver) is best of selenium 3.141.0?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I've been trying to get `selenium` to work on my Raspberry Pi 4 for a while now but I'm continuously getting this error when running it normally with `geckodriver 0.23.0 ( 2018-10-04 )`:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

and another error similar to this:

```
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

It would tell me how it couldn't find Firefox in PATH that I was to install Firefox binary if it hadn't been installed yet.  I used the following command to install what seems to be the only compatible version of `Firefox` for my operating system:

```sh
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

I tried my script again, but would get this instead:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that I'm using Raspbian OS (Lite), meaning that it runs in a terminal based environment, but this isn't very concerning because I could most likely just use a virtual environment.  BUT, this is not what I want.  Before upgrading my Pi, I was able to use selenium perfectly fine, the same version of selenium, but in headless mode.

Why do I have to install Firefox if I already have `geckodriver` and `selenium` all set into place?

Using `Python3.9.1`

Answer (score 0):

Had to preset FirefoxBinary to headless:

```py
binary = FirefoxBinary()
binary.add_command_line_options("--headless")

Driver = Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```